# Android Studio not launching on windows 7

Tags: android

I have installed android studio on windows 7, when I try to launch it, it shows this error window (I didn't find something similar here)

[image]

I have uninstalled and installed it again but shows the same... if anyone knows how to solve it I'd be glad to know, thank you!

Comment: Have you install jdk properly?

Comment: This doesn't appear to be a programming question, therefore it's off-topic here.

Answer (score -1):

Turn off the Internet connection and try again.

Comment: Please add this to comment

Comment: Is the answer... LOL